# Infinite load for CollectionView does not work and RemainingItemsThresholdReached never get fired?

Tags: xamarin, maui, .net-maui

I'm trying to load CollectionView incrementally but RemainingItemsThresholdReached never get fired, I tried to use RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand also but no luck.

Here is my code, hope someone can figure out what's going wrong.

```
<CollectionView x:Name="collectionView" ItemsSource="{Binding Users}"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always"
                        RemainingItemsThreshold="3"
                         RemainingItemsThresholdReached="LoadMoreAsync" >
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <Border Stroke="White" Background="Black" StrokeThickness="2"
        Padding="8" Margin="10">
                <Border.StrokeShape>
                    <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="10,10,10,10"/>
                </Border.StrokeShape>
                        <StackLayout >
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="20" Padding="10">
                        <Image Source="download.png" HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="40" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding UserName}" FontSize="14" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    </StackLayout>
                    <BoxView Color="Gray" HeightRequest="2" HorizontalOptions="Fill" />
                        <Label Padding="7" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                    <BoxView Color="Gray" HeightRequest="1" HorizontalOptions="Fill" />
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="20" Padding="10">
                        <Grid   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition  Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition  Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ImageButton  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="user.png" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" />
                            <ImageButton  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Source="like.png" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" />
                            <ImageButton  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Source="chat.png" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" />
                        </Grid>

                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </Border>

        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

the backend side:

```
 public void LoadMoreAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsBusy)
            return;

        IsBusy = true;

        GetUsers(pageNumber, 6);
        pageNumber++;

        IsBusy = false;
    }
```

Comment: 1) A breakpoint on first line of `LoadMoreAsync` is never reached, when scroll? 2) What is value of `Users.Count`, when you start scrolling? 3) Is it showing any Users at all? 4) As a test, add a button on the page. Have button click method do `GetUsers(pageNumber, 6); pageNumber++;` Does that successfully add users?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve yes the breakpoint of first line of  LoadMoreAsync is never reached, the value of Users..Count when I start scrolling is 6 and the CollectionsView shows the 6 users but when I scroll down no more users added to the list. I placed button to mock the scrolls and it successfully add more users

Comment: ok, that seems to rule out any problem with your code. I think it is an actual Maui bug. For target, did you select "Local Machine" (eg. Windows), or an Android or iOS Emulator? Best way to get this fixed is to make a small public github repo with just enough code to run and show the problem. Then create a new [github maui issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues). If you do, please add a link in that issue back to here, and a link here to that issue.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve actually I tried it on "Local Machine" and on android device both have the same issue

Comment: Try if this works with RemainingItemsThreshold="1", if it does report a bug.

Comment: @NickKovalsky same issue.

Comment: Could you please post a basic demo so that we can test on our side?